# Insert into table from another using custom data

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-insert

As I read [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/database_guides/Practical_PostgreSQL_database/PostgreSQL_x5504_002.htm) If I want to insert into a table from another in PostgreSQL database I have to use this:

This query inserts some rows from another table

```
INSERT INTO books (id, title, author_id, subject_id)
       SELECT nextval('book_ids'), title, author_id, subject_id
              FROM book_queue WHERE approved;
```

But how can I insert a row with more columns with my custom data(default or non default)?

E.g., `books (id, title, author_id, <a cell with my data1>,subject_id,<a cell with my data2>)`

And how can I update a selected data before inserting into a table?

I.e., something like:

```
INSERT INTO books (id, title, author_id, subject_id)
       SELECT nextval('book_ids'), title, author_id+1, subject_id/2
              FROM book_queue WHERE approved;
```

Comment: What exactly is `<a cell with my dataX>`? Is that a row from some other table? Some other well-defined data? The way you phrase your question you will not get a proper answer; please provide more details.

Comment: This is some integer value or string value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert inserts rows, and select generates/*forms* rows, so if you can build the data you want to insert with any `select` statement, then you can insert it, even if there are new fields or updated fields. For example:

```
INSERT INTO books (title, author_id, subject_id, combined)
  SELECT title, author_id+1, subject_id/2, author_id || ' ' || title
    FROM book_queue WHERE approved;
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4b48d/1) to play with.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I want. This is very difficult to find good examples. Congratulate with 1k scores:)